# Which complex exponent can turn x into a -x?

Tags: complex-numbers

Actually that is, I would like to use a complex exponent to turn a number `x` into an `-x` just by applying some complex exponent to `x`. I think I would have to use some `ln`, `π` and so one, but I am actually stack and cannot find the correct path to solving it.

For example, let's say for `2` we choose the real part to be equal `1`, what would be the solution for `y` in this special case.

$$
2^{1 + iy}=-2
$$

What would be the solution for the imaginary part of `z` if the real part must be `0.5`?

$$
x^{0.5 + iy} = -x
$$

$$
x^{0.5} * x^{iy} = \sqrt{x} * -\sqrt{x} = -x
$$

What is `y` in this case?

Is there maybe a general solution for

$$
x^{z}=-x
$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+e%5E(i*x*a)%3D-a

Comment: Unless $x$ happens to be a positive real number, this equation $x^z = -x$ is not well-defined for $z$ other than integers.  Of course it will be fairly rare that $x$ allows an integer exponent solution.

Comment: Actually I just would like to understand it for $$2^z=-2$$ and $$3^z=-3$$ Specially in the case where $$ real part of (z) = 0.5 $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=1+\frac{i\pi}{\ln(x)}$ for $x\neq 0$, and $f(x)=1$ for $x=0$. Then $x^{f(x)}=-x$ for all $x\in\Re_0^+$.

This is obvious for $x=0$. For $x\neq 0$ we have: $-x=x(-1) = x^{1+\log_x (-1)} =  x ^{1+\frac{\ln(-1)}{\ln(x)}} = 
x ^{1+\frac{i\pi}{\ln(x)}}$.

Comment: That is clearly not what OP means.

Comment: Is there a solution like this, where the real part is `0.5` ?

Comment: @Lovsovs it may be clear to you, but it's certainly not clear to me. The OP is asking for $f(x)$ such that $x^{f(x)}=-1$ for all $x$. Now, $f(x)=1+\frac{i\pi}{\ln(x)}$ satisfies the requirement. What's wrong with that?

Comment: What if $x$ is not real?

Comment: A lot of editing has been going on since then, I have no problem with your answer now!

Comment: Indeed there are more solutions of the type $x ^{1+\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{\ln(x)}i}$ for integer $k$ (assuming $x$ is a positive real)

Comment: hmm, ok it plays well if real part is `1`, @Anonymous is there a nice solution if real part is `0.5`?

Comment: @webdeb not for *all* x! This is obvious e.g. for $x=e$, since $e^{1/2+iy}$ with $y\in\Re$ has modulus $\sqrt{e}\neq e$. For *some* x (say, $0$ :)) it certainly works.

Comment: Ok, I just would like to know what the solution would be for x = 2 or 3

Comment: @webdeb Well, for $x=2$ you have $f(x)=1+\frac{i\pi}{\ln(2)}$. In fact, as Henry pointed out, for any integer k, $f_k(x)=1+\frac{(2k+1)i\pi}{\ln(2)}$ will work. But if you are working with a positive real $x$, the real part of $f(x)$ can't be chosen arbitrarily (say, $0.5$) if you want $x^{f(x)}$ and $x$ to have the same modulus.

Comment: Oh, no the real part is `1`, is it doable when the real part is 1/2?

Comment: I mean is there a way to calculate `yi` if the real part is `1/2`

Comment: it would mea the `x^yi` would result in $$-\sqrt{x} $$

Comment: @webdeb AH! That's something *completely* different! You should open a different question.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense I did: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183668/complex-exponent-with-real-part-1-2-should-convert-x-into-x