# Complex exponent with real part = 1/2 should convert x into -x

Tags: complex-numbers

Complex $z$ is given as $\frac{1}{2} + yi$

1. What is $y$ if

$$
2^{\frac{1}{2} + yi} = -2
$$

2. What is $y$ if

$$
3^{\frac{1}{2} + yi} = -3
$$

How to calculate it for other values?

Comment: No, it's a different question.

Comment: @Anonymous I don't see how this is different from the $x^{0.5 + iy} = -x\,$ asked in the other question.

Comment: @dxiv after Anonymous answered the question you mentioned, I updated the content, this question should really concentrate on the special problem

Comment: @webdeb If anything, I'd suggest you update the *title* of the question. Because it does not reflect the question. When you say "which complex exponent with real part 1/2", you mean which complex $z$ in the form $1/2+iy$ **with a real y**. There is no such real $y$, $y$ has to have an imaginary part to "bring up" that $1/2$ to $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve the generic problem $c^{1/2+iy}=-c$ for any $c\in\Re^+$. Observe that $-c$ has modulus $c$, and phase $\pi$. Let's write $y=a+ib$ with $a,b\in\Re$. Then $c^{1/2+iy}=c^{1/2+ia-b}$. We must have:

$\frac1{2}-b=1$, so $b=-\frac{1}{2}$, and

$a\ln(c)=(2k+1)\pi$, for some integer $k$, so $a=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{\ln(c)}$, (note that *any* integer $k$ will do) and thus

$y=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{\ln(c)}-\frac{1}{2}i$

Comment: Haha, well then its actually just 1/2 + 1/2 + yi

Comment: So is there a solution for $$2^ai = -\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: @webdeb that looks like a different question to me... but note that you are asking for an $a$ such that $2^{a+i\pi/(2\ln(2))}=2^{1/2+i\pi}$...

Comment: No, see x^1/2+yi= -x = x^1/2 * x^yi , isnt it?

Comment: @webdeb in general, for these types of problems, the easiest solution is to write all terms to the form $e^{a+ib}$ with $a,b\in \Re$ (remembering that $i=e^{i\left(2k+\frac1{2}\right)\pi}$).

Comment: I still didnt get the whole thing, I'll just keep on studying, thanks